# Should I be worried about doing a hard reset on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, restart

​Just for my curiosity and knowledge, from a Software and Hardware stand point prospective, the other day I was having a discussion with some iPhone users.

The topic was the Hard Reset that you can apply by press and hold both the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons for at least ten seconds, until you see the Apple logo. As you already know, most of the time, this method fix so many iOS issues.

Now, some of them say that it is safe to do, as many time you want the hard reset, some other say that even if it is safe to do it, it is always recommend to have an iCloud or iTunes backup before do the hard reset due to kernel panic, lost of pictures during the rebuild of the library, etc.

What is the real answer on that?

Comment: I'd refer to it as a hard-restart. It doesn't rebuild any libraries, and it essentially force-quits the kernel, so there's no time for a kernel panic.

Answer (score 1):

A hard-resart is perfectly okay to do. However, I believe some may be mistaking this for a DFU (Device Firmware Upgrade) which has a similar process of initiating and will essentially force you to restore or wipe your device.

Answer (score 0):

A hard restart is **perfectly fine** to do. I do it multiple times every week, without issues, and I never worry about not having a recent iTunes backup before I hard restart my iPhone or iPad. All one is essentially doing by holding the home button and sleep/wake button is turning the iDevice off, then back on, it just saves a little time and in some cases is necessary due to the normal way to power off an iPhone not working due to the iPhone not responding.